# Can't able to load page. SecurityError: The operation is insecure

Tags: java, security, selenium, certificate

Am using selenium with java

While executing this line

```
driver.get("http://mobile.twitter.com/");
```

Am getting error as below in console:-

SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

Comment: Did you try https://?

Comment: @Gray Yes i tried both https and http